# Confused about go syntax

Tags: go

Little bit confused with this code.

```
var _ QueryAppender = (*selectQuery)(nil)
```

I found this code in [pg-go](https://github.com/go-pg/pg/blob/master/orm/select.go)
 repository and don't know why `QueryAppender` declared that way. Please explain me what is the use cases when I should declare variables that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't do anything at runtime, but unless the `*selectQuery` type satisfies the interface `QueryAppender`, compilation will fail. It's a kind of static assertion.